# Version Spring URI

Tags: spring, api, rest, spring-mvc, version

We have a requirement wherein we want ***optional versioning*** for all our REST APIs.
For e.g both the following ***must be*** supported

- /employee/1
- v1.1/employee/1

We are using ***Spring 3.1*** currently. Can anyone please let me know if it is possible to achieve the above.

We want to make the modification preferably at a single place without having to create multiple @RequestMapping annotated methods.

If this question with the specific version of spring has been answered, can you please point me to the same. Thank you.